# Codeigniter ION-AUTH not showing error on same email address entry

Tags: codeigniter, ion-auth

I am facing a problem that is when i try to update my email address, if i add a new email which already exists on the database, it should show an error. But its not showing.

The code is returning an error msg. But its not showing it in the view. really need the solution.

my ajax call ::

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('#info_form').serialize()  + '&timezone=' + x + '&timezone_name=' + y,

        url: '<?php echo site_url('profile/change_info')?>',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.status == 'ok') {

                manual_on(y);
                clearState();
                $('#bullet').removeClass("message-icon-on").addClass("message-icon");
                $('.change').attr('data-id','1').html('Auto Detect Your Timezone: Off');




                $('#profile_message').html(response.message);
                $('#profile_message').children("p").addClass("type-ok").delay(4000).fadeOut(400).css('display', 'block');;
                $('#email_label').html($('input[name=email]', '#info_edit').val());
                $('#info_form')[0].reset();



                switchToView();

                return;
            } else if (response.status == 'validation_error') {
                var first_printed = false;
                $.each(response.fields_statuses, function (field, value) {
                    if (value.status != 'ok' && !first_printed) {
                        $('#profile_message').html(value.message);
                        $('#profile_message').children("p").addClass("type-error").delay(4000).fadeOut(400).css('display', 'block');;
                        first_printed = true;
                    }
                    var input = $('input[name=' + field + ']', '#info_form');
                    show_input_validation(input, value);
                });
                return;
            }
            outputAjaxMessage('#register_message', response);
        }
    });
```

and my controller:

```
 public function change_info()
{
    $fields = array('email','password','passwconf');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'e-mail', 'required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required|min_length[' .
        $this->config->item('min_password_length', 'ion_auth') . ']|max_length[' .
        $this->config->item('max_password_length', 'ion_auth') . ']|matches[passwconf]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('passwconf', 'password confirmation', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
        $email = strtolower($this->input->post('email'));
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $timezone = $this->input->post('timezone');
        $timezone_name = $this->input->post('timezone_name');
        //$auto_timezone = $this->input->post('auto_timezone'); 

            if($timezone!="undefined" || $timezone_name!="undefined"){
                if ($this->ion_auth->update($this->data['my_id'], array('password' => $password, 'email' => $email, 'timezone'=> $timezone, 'timezone_name' => $timezone_name))==TRUE) {
                    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'ok', 'message' => $this->ion_auth->messages()));
                } else {
                    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'message' => $this->ion_auth->errors()));
                }
              }else{
                if ($this->ion_auth->update($this->data['my_id'], array('password' => $password, 'email' => $email))) {
                    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'ok', 'message' => $this->ion_auth->messages()));
                } else {
                    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'message' => $this->ion_auth->errors()));
                }   
              }
              } else {
        foreach($fields as $field){
            $field_statuses[$field] = array(
                'status'=>form_error($field)=='' ? 'ok' : 'warning',
                'message' =>form_error($field));
        }

        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'validation_error', 'fields_statuses' => $field_statuses));
    }

}
```

my model

```
 public function update($id, array $data)
{
    $this->trigger_events('pre_update_user');

    $user = $this->user($id)->row();

    $this->db->trans_begin();



    if ($this->identity_column == 'email' && $this->email_check($email)) {
            $this->set_error('account_creation_duplicate_email');
            return FALSE;
        } elseif ($this->identity_column == 'username' && $this->username_check($username)) {
            $this->set_error('account_creation_duplicate_username');
            return FALSE;
        }







    $data['auto_timezone']=0;// turning timezone auto detection off
    if (array_key_exists($this->identity_column, $data) && $this->identity_check($data[$this->identity_column]) && $user->{$this->identity_column} !== $data[$this->identity_column]) {
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
        $this->set_error('account_creation_duplicate_' . $this->identity_column);

        $this->trigger_events(array('post_update_user', 'post_update_user_unsuccessful'));
        $this->set_error('update_unsuccessful');

        return FALSE;
    }




    // Filter the data passed
    $data = $this->_filter_data($this->tables['users'], $data);

    if (array_key_exists('username', $data) || array_key_exists('password', $data) || array_key_exists('email', $data) || array_key_exists('timezone', $data)) {
        if (array_key_exists('password', $data)) {
            if (!empty($data['password'])) {
                $data['password'] = $this->hash_password($data['password'], $user->salt);
            } else {
                // unset password so it doesn't effect database entry if no password passed
                unset($data['password']);
            }
        }
    }

    $this->trigger_events('extra_where');
    $this->db->update($this->tables['users'], $data, array('id' => $user->id));

    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
        $this->db->trans_rollback();

        $this->trigger_events(array('post_update_user', 'post_update_user_unsuccessful'));
        $this->set_error('update_unsuccessful');
        return FALSE;
    }

    $this->db->trans_commit();

    $this->trigger_events(array('post_update_user', 'post_update_user_successful'));
    $this->set_message('update_successful');
    return TRUE;
}
```